# C++ class [ ] operator weird output

Tags: c++, string, class, operators, c++17

In the following code, I input a vector of strings which is supposed to be a list of messages. The [ ] operator should then return a specified message to me. For example, if I input:

```
vector<string> m = {
    "Element 0",
    "Attack - at - midnight",
    "Element 2"};
```

into the following class by saying: `SelfDestructingMessage sdm(m);`
,then `sdm[1];` should return `"Attack - at - midnight"`. However, the return I am given instead is `"\xA0\xABO\xF2\x98U\0\0 at - midnight"`. Any tips in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
class SelfDestructingMessage { // This is my class, fairly straight forward
    private:
        vector<string> messages_;
    public:
            // Constructor
        SelfDestructingMessage(vector<string>);
            // Getter
        vector<string> messages() const {return messages_;}
            // Overloaded Operator
        string const& operator[](size_t);
}

SelfDestructingMessage::SelfDestructingMessage(vector<string> messages){ // Constructor
    messages_ = messages;
}

string const& SelfDestructingMessage::operator[](size_t index){ // Having trouble here
    long signed_index = index;
    string const& message = messages().at(signed_index);
    return message;
}
```

Comment: `vector<string> const & messages(void) const`

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that little dance with `signed_index` in `operator[]` is superfluous. The entire function body can simply be `return messages_[index];`. If you also want to provide checked access, use `SelfDestructingMessage::at()`, so that the interface is consistent with the standard library.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! However, this code is for my programming class and there is more to the [ ] operator that I didn't include because it wasn't relevant to my question

Answer (score 2):

The `messages` function returns a temporary copy of the vector. This temporary vector will end its life-time as soon as the expression `messages().at(signed_index)` is finished, leaving all reverences to elements in it invalid.

Your `messages` function needs to return a reference to the vector instead:

```
vector<string> const & messages(void) const;
```

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense! However, after replacing the function I was left with an error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "SelfDestructingMessage::messages() const", referenced from: SelfDestructingMessage::operator[](unsigned long) in self_destructing-b14d93.o`

Comment: Never mind ignore that I got it! Thank you so much I appreciate it greatly